# How to fix This expression is not callable. Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I simply tried to check if 'USER_ADMIN' is exist in user.roles
that code works perfectly in Node.js, but when I came to my react-TypeScript project
I get this error:

```
src/context/AuthContext.tsx:24:34 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures.

24       let isAdminTest: boolean = isAdmin("ROLE_ADMIN", roles);
```

My AuthContext here:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AuthContextType, ChildProps } from "../@types";

const initialState: AuthContextType = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  isAdmin: false,
  login(username, email, token) {},
  logout() {},
};

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(initialState);

const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }: ChildProps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const userData = localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (userData) {
      const user = JSON.parse(userData);
      const token = user.token;
      const email = user.email;
      const username = user.username;
      const roles = user.roles;

      //isAdminTest = false/true
      let isAdminTest: boolean = isAdmin("ROLE_ADMIN", roles);
      login(username, email, token);
    }
  }, []);

  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  const login = (username: string, email: string, token: string) => {
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
    setEmail(email);
    setUsername(username);
    setToken(token);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
    setToken(undefined);
    setEmail(undefined);
    setUsername(undefined);
  };
  //what we want to expose/share with the app:
  const contextValues = {
    isAdmin,
    isLoggedIn,
    username,
    token,
    email,
    login,
    logout,
  };
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

//the provider is only used in index.tsx <Provider>
export { AuthContext, AuthContextProvider };

//used in all the app:
export default AuthContext;
```

And this is my function that checks if string is exist on some array

```
const isAdmin = (string: string, arr: string[]) => {
  let isTrue: boolean = false;
  arr.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (string === value) {
      isTrue = true;
    }
  });
  return isTrue;
};
export default isAdmin;
```

That code works perfectly in Node.js, but in react TypeScript it says this error.

Comment: Your `isAdmin` for `src/context/AuthContext.tsx:24:34` is the one in `const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);`, not the function you have in the other file

Comment: omg, how i didnt see it? thanks so much m8

Answer (score 0):

> Your `isAdmin` for `src/context/AuthContext.tsx:24:34` is the one in `const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);`, not the function you have in the other file - [qrsngky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4225384/qrsngky)